# Is 600W power supply enough for HD 7970 and GTX 970 (working at the same time)?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I have 600W power supply (OCZ Stealthxstream 2 600W) in my pc. I use currently Asus Radeon HD 7970 graphics card but would like to buy second card (GTX 970) and use both cards at the same time at full power (but not overclocked).

When this one card I have is used at full capacity I measured that computer draws around 245W of power. The second card power requirements are around 150W.

I have only three 4-pin molex connectors free left (two are already used to power first card) and the new card would require two 6-pin connectors. Could I split one 4-pin into two 4-pin connectors and then use two 2x4-pin to 6-pin adapters?

Would I be able to use current power supply in this setup?

**Edit**: with all four CPU cores at 100% the power consumption is right now around 303W, but I don't expect to use that much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphics card and PSU requirement](http://superuser.com/questions/1035218/graphics-card-and-psu-requirement)

Comment: It won't work. Will crash at peeks. How do you want to use both cards at the same time anyway (just curious)?

Comment: Not enough of the proper connectors on the power supply is a bad sign.

Comment: @fixer1234, answers in those link do not answer my specific question.

Comment: @FlashThunder, OpenCL/CUDA computations

Comment: Thanks for posting back.  I retracted the close as duplicate vote.

Comment: The Asus is a pretty big card, are you going to have any problems putting them side by side in suitable PCI-e lanes on your motherboard for what you are looking to do?

Comment: @Mark, 7970 takes 3 lots, 970 - 2 lots, I have motherboard with 3 slots spacing between PCI-E slots, so I'm going to put 970 at the top to have one slot for ventilation.

Comment: My response is updated.

Comment: Paweł: I am quite sure, it won't work... I mean it won't be stable.

Comment: @FlashThunder, but why? Everything adds up to 450W and there is still large margin.

Answer (score 1):

(edited based on edit of OP)

It will work, barely. If the MB and both cards go to %100 draw, you are in trouble, as that is essentially 600 watts of load.

I strongly recommend either upgrading the psu or using a supplementary psu like the Juice Box, or the epower EP-450CD to power one of the cards.

That rig will not be stable, particularly under high cpu load.

Comment: how can you answer that not even knowing the rest of config? 0_o

Comment: @FlashThunder, what other config do you want to know?

Comment: PC uses up to 300W with GPU and CPU at 100%. Adding second card will make this 450W. PSU is still below 80% usage. So, why this won't work?

Comment: This is average usage, not at peek. I'm telling you, you'll get BSODs. Try yourself if you don't believe me.