# Is an Abtec CE2 hb1003 (550W) enough to power an GTX 970?

Tags: power-supply, gpu, build

Would an Abtec CE2 hb1003 (http://www.acbel.com/eng/Product.aspx?id=42&&sd=31&&pid=242) be enough to power a GTX 970 or 960 4gb? Thanks

Comment: Dupe: [Graphics card and PSU requirement](http://superuser.com/q/1035218)

Answer (score -2):

Per these specs (http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-960/specifications) the 500W CE2 HB1003 power supply appears to be sufficient for the Geforce GTX 960 (only requires 400W, ~80%), but I would not use it to power the 970 since it needs 500W. This power supply has an OPP (over power protection) of 550W meaning it will protect itself by disconnecting or dropping power output when requirements get to 550W - that seems critically close to a problem, IMO.

This is my suggestion based on 25+ years of electrical experience.