# How to calculate the number of watts for every addiotnal part to my pc?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, power-supply, power, dell-optiplex

Could you help me how to calculate the number of devices I could add to my computer safely to the limit of the power supply (290 watt)

I have [Dell 9020 core i5 tower pc](https://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/optiplex-9020-micro-technical-spec-sheet.pdf)

and I want to add the following:

- Internal SATA black western harddisk `3tb`
- Internal SATA harddisk `1tb` samsung

in addition to the existing `500 gb` blue western harddisk

- 1 RAM DDR3 -->`4gb` in addition to the existing one so the sum = `8 gb`
- `2tb` external usb harddisk

Is this safe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphics card and PSU requirement](https://superuser.com/questions/1035218/graphics-card-and-psu-requirement)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's safe to add these components. To be sure, use a wattage calculator like this:

https://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator